How to manage logic in Compose Desktop MenuBar? (navigation, etc...)
I want to add a windows top menu bar, like in windows applications. I found MenuBar, but... how to deal with navigation or logic in general in MenuBar? All the screens of my application and navigation logic are on my commonMain module.
Navigation logic needs to be also present on my commonMain screens because they can also navigate between them with buttons, the same navigation that must have the MenuBar should be shared between MenuBar and the screens buttons navigation. This is like when you access the "Window" or "Screen" sections of a windows app top menu bar, they allow you navigate, but you also can switch screens with some buttons in the UI of the windows application.
NAVIGATION PROBLEM:
MenuBar is a desktop only composable, so it must be created on the Window of the desktopMain module, before displaying any ui screen placed on the commonMain module. If it needs to execute navigation, it need to hold a instance of the navcontroller, and to pass the navcontroller down in the appstateholder to the commonMain module screens. I followed the pattern in nowinandroid app:
https://github.com/android/nowinandroid/blob/d15c739812f25401b21614fe0f7e18534d285921/app/src/main/kotlin/com/google/samples/apps/nowinandroid/ui/NiaAppState.kt#L54
I created an appstateholder class with the navcontroller, and I instantiated that in the commonMain package:
@Stable
class AppStateHolder(
    val navController: NavHostController = NavHostController()
) {
    // UI State
    val currentDestination: NavDestination?
        @Composable get() = navController
            .currentBackStackEntryAsState().value?.destination

    // UI logic
    fun navigate(route: String) {
        navController.navigate(route)
    }
}

This is my desktopMain window:
fun main() = application {
    initKoin(
        databaseBuilder = createDatabaseBuilder(),
    )

    val windowState = rememberWindowState(
        size = DpSize(1200.dp, 900.dp),
        position = WindowPosition(Alignment.Center)
    )

    val appStateHolder= remember { AppStateHolder() }

    Window(
        onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication,
        title = stringResource(Res.string.app_name),
        state = windowState
    ) {
        WindowsMenuBar(
            onNavigation = { route -> appStateHolder.navigate(route) },
            onExitEvent = ::exitApplication
        )

        MyApplicationTheme {
            App(appStateHolder)
        }
    }
}

Then, in my commonMain package I receive that appStateHolder and use it for navigation:
@Composable
fun App(appStateHolder: AppStateHolder) {

    NavHost(
        navController = appStateHolder.navController,
        startDestination = ScreenRoute.MainScreen.name
    ) {
        composable(ScreenRoute.MainScreen.name) {
            MainScreen(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
                onBusStopsDBButtonClicked = { appStateHolder.navigate(ScreenRoute.BusStopsDB.name) }
            )
        }

Well, this doesn't work, and gives me this runtime error on composable(ScreenRoute.MainScreen.name) line of my desktopMain module:

Navigator with class "class
androidx.navigation.compose.ComposeNavigator". You must call
NavController.addNavigator() for each navigation type.

How can I solve it?
LOGIC PROBLEM:
If for example, if I want to display an "about" or a "help" dialog in my desktop app, that logic should be executed from a viewmodel, but MenuBar is always visible and shared by the entire application, visible on every screen, and each one of the screens of my app has their own viewmodel, which is exclusive of the screen, without having references to the MenuBar... does that mean that I need two viewmodels coexisting at the same moment? one for the window of the app, managing the menubar events and other for the current visible screen? This seems to be very confusing.
